# Why does the Typescript compiler infer return type of functions as `primitive type` while the return value is a known value?

Tags: typescript, types, casting, type-conversion, typeerror

As you can see in below code, the TS compiler **infers** the type as :

```js
const message = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "hello, can you here me" : null;
```

So **message** variable is inferred as `"hello, can you here me" | null`, which makes sense, as there are two absolute possible values, however in this example bellow the return value is still an absolute value, but the getName type is `string` primitive type not `John Gump`

```js
const getName = () => "John Gump";
```

Comment: Did you mean to execute that function before assigning it to `getName`? Right now, its type is a function returning a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the rules about widening of literal types which concern this question were written down in [PR/#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676).

---

Let's look at the first expression:

```js
const message = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "hello, can you here me" : null;
```

The first rule applicable to this statement is the following:

> The type of a string or numeric literal occurring in an expression is a widening literal type.

The expression itself is inferred to be a *"widening literal type"* which is a literal type that can be widened by the compiler **as appropriate**.

But is it appropriate in our example? The PR states that

> The type inferred for a const variable or readonly property without a type annotation is the type of the initializer as-is.

As `message` is  a `const` variable, the type of the *widened literal type* of the expression is *not* widened and stays `"hello, can you here me" | null`.

The compiler would find widening appropriate for a `let` variable.

```
let message = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "hello, can you here me" : null;
//  ^? message: string | null
```

---

When it comes to inferred function return types, the PR states that

> In a function with no return type annotation, if the inferred return type is a literal type (but not a literal union type) and the function does not have a contextual type with a return type that includes literal types, the return type is widened to its widened literal type

Let's look again at the function:

```
const getName = () => "John Gump";
```

We can see that indeed the functions return type would be a literal type `"John Gump"`. This is not a union and there is also no *contextual type* which concludes to the return type being widened to its widened literal type `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Math.random() return value between 0 and 1. Therefore message var always be null.

Comment: In runtime yes, but not from the TS point of view.

Comment: However, I changed `3` to `0.5`, although the inference will remain the same, but the question will become more valid. thanks.

Comment: That's not even really what the question is asking about. I think this is a comment.