# ReturnType won't catch return type of a fuction that's returning string or number values

Tags: typescript, string, types, numbers, return

Can anyone please explain to me why `ReturnType` can infer a function's exact return values when there's an `if` statement, but only can infer **types of the value** when the function returns one guaranteed string or number value?

In `testA`, `ReturnType<typeof testA>` could successfully infer the return values, 1 and 2.

However, in the case of `testB`(return one value), `ReturnType<typeof testB>` can only infer the type, `number`.

Why a function that returns only can guess literally the **type** of the return value which is `number`

It behaves the same with `string` values. (second screenshot)

[image: the case with number]

[image: the case with string]

Comment: Because ts calculate type of `1` as number, and return type of function testB is number

Comment: @vbykovsky Yes, I understand that. But what about the `testA`? It also returns 1 and 2 which are numbers, but why the `type A` could successfully guess the exact value of the function `testA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to [`type widening`](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/literal-type-widening-in-typescript)

The following resources will be useful:

- [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74528499/why-does-the-typescript-compiler-infer-return-type-of-functions-as-primitive-ty) explaining the behaviour
- The [TypeScript PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676) (referenced in the above answer) which explains the rules for when a literal type is widened or not

An explicit excerpt from the above PR outlines the behaviour observed

> In a function with no return type annotation, if the inferred return type is a literal type (but not a literal union type) and the function does not have a contextual type with a return type that includes literal types, the return type is widened to its widened literal type:
>
> ```
> function foo() {
>     return "hello";
> }
>
> function bar() {
>     return cond ? "foo" : "bar";
> }
>
> const c1 = foo();  // string
> const c2 = bar();  // "foo" | "bar"
> ```

---

A couple of simple ways to address this are:

- Leverage `as const` on the functions return value
- Provide an explicit return type on the function (as your function definition, e.g. `return 1` satisfies the return type constraint, there is no need for inferrence and thus potential widening)

```
const testA = (v: boolean) => v ? 1 : 2;         // (v: boolean) => 1 | 2
const testB = (v: boolean) => 1;                 // (v: boolean) => number
const constTestB = (v: boolean) => 1 as const;   // (v: boolean) => 1
const typedTestB = (v: boolean): 1 => 1;         // (v: boolean) => 1
```

https://tsplay.dev/w2pyzm

Comment: thank you for the links and explanations. The `if` statement makes the return values as `union` type. Therefore, it exactly guesses the return value as the return type. Otherwise, it has no contextual type, so the `ReturnType` infer the return value as widened literal type!